# I want to know the pattern and logic in this code

Tags: go

i am new to Go so i need to know the pattern and understand the logic in this code

first :
in the car model folder lying a .go file name car.go but its struct was

and in controller folder there a cars.go file as following

```
type Car struct {
    Id        bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id"`
    Model     string        `bson:"model" form:"" json:"model" binding:"required"`
    Brand     string        `bson:"brand" form:"brand" json:"brand" binding:"required"`
    CreatedAt bson.MongoTimestamp
}

type CarController struct {
    carService *services.CarService
}

func (controller CarController) New() *CarController {
    controller.carService = services.CarService{}.New()

    return &controller
}

func (controller CarController) GetIndex(c *gin.Context) {
    carList := controller.carService.Find(&bson.M{})
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, &carList)
    //fmt.Println(carList) }
}
```

and in service folder was a carService.go file as following

```
type CarService struct {
    dbName         string
    uri            string
    collectionName string
}

func (r CarService) New() *CarService {
    configManger := viperconfing.Config{}
    r.uri = configManger.GetConfig("dbUri")
    r.dbName = configManger.GetConfig("dbName")
    r.collectionName = "car"
    return &r
}

func (r CarService) Find(query *bson.M) (cars []models.Car) {
    session, _ := mgo.Dial(r.uri)
    defer session.Close()
    session.SetSafe(&mgo.Safe{})
    collection := session.DB(r.dbName).C(r.collectionName)

    collection.Find(query).All(&cars)

    fmt.Println(cars)
    return cars
}
```

I want to know the pattern used in this code i to understand the full logic and what is * meaning ??

Comment: This might not be a great question for the format of Stack Overflow: your question is very broad. Try asking on https://forum.golangbridge.org/ and be clear about what parts of the code you don't understand (add comments to those sections stating what is unclear).

Comment: good what is * meaning ??

Answer (score 2):

`*` is a pointer.

Please stop everything that you are doing and take the Go [tour](https://tour.golang.org/).

Comment: thanks i am now there